# Qt quick controls ListView size issue

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I have some problem with popup window size behavior using Qt Quick Controls 2. When I'm putting ListView as contentItem for Popup window, Popup window size is zero. Some sample code that reproduce issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Button {
        text: "open popup"
        onClicked: popup.open()
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        x: (window.width - width) / 2
        y: window.height / 6
        width: contentWidth
        height: contentHeight

        contentItem: ListView {
            width: contentWidth
            height: contentHeight
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {
                    name: "Apple"
                    cost: 2.45
                }
                ListElement {
                    name: "Orange"
                    cost: 3.25
                }
                ListElement {
                    name: "Banana"
                    cost: 1.95
                }
            }

            delegate: RowLayout {
                Label {
                    text: name
                }
                Label {
                    text: cost
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to make popup adopt to the size of ListView?

Comment: What is `contentWidth`/`contentHeight`?

Comment: According to the documentation: "This property holds the content width. It is used for calculating the total implicit width of the Popup."

Comment: If you want your popup window will be with same size as `contentItem` just do nothing. According to the docs: `If only a single item is used within a Popup, it will resize to fit the implicit size of its contained item`

Comment: In your example that doesn't make sense. You set popup size to contentItem size (by setting `width: contentWidth; height: contentHeight`) and simultaneously set the size of `contentItem` to that.

Comment: I've tried to remove `width: contentWidth` `height: contentHeight` both for `Popup` and `ListView` still has zero size. `contentWidth` `contentHeight` parameters for `Popup` and `ListView` isn't the same. `contentWidth` `contentHeight` parameters for `ListView` is the size of delegates, for `Popup` it is size of ListView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vertical `ListView` does not provide content width. It is always `-1`. You'll have to specify something, for example:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    x: (window.width - width) / 2
    y: window.height / 6

    contentItem: ListView {
        implicitWidth: 200 // <==
        implicitHeight: contentHeight
        //...
    }
}
```